sonatype nexus работа в режиме синхронизации
Есть репозиторий (debian) в интернете и есть сеть предприятия у которой связь с интернетом может пропадать. Я понимаю что  sonatype nexus задумывался для других сценариев работы, но всё же, могу ли я его настроить, что бы он синхронизировал заданный репозиторий? Что бы добавлял и удалал пакеты в случаи изменения репозитория в интернете?
